# How to limit posts by category

Tags: posts, categories, limit

I was wondering if there is a way to make this code limit by category. In other words, if user A has already published 10 posts in category A then he can keep the new ones as drafts in category A or post another 10 in category B.

```
*
* @param array $data                An array of slashed, sanitized, and processed post data.
* @param array $postarr             An array of sanitized (and slashed) but otherwise unmodified post data.
* @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters
* @return {[type]}          [description]
*/
function kia_limit_posts( $data, $postarr )  {

  if ( isset( $data['post_type'] ) && 'post' === $data['post_type'] ) {
  
      $posts_per_month = 10; // Could be set as an updatable option
      $user_id         = get_current_user_id();
      
      // Number of posts in current month by this user
      $author_posts = new WP_Query( array(
          'post_type'     => 'any',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'author'        => $user_id,
          'fields'        => 'ids',
          'monthnum'      => date( 'm' ), // Whatever the current month is
      ) );
      
      $author_post_count = $author_posts = $author_posts->post_count + 1; // Add current post
      
      if( $author_post_count > $posts_per_month ) {
          $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
      }
  
  }
  return $data;
  
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'kia_limit_posts', 10, 2 );
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @kero this code limits posts from any category, but I want to limit it by category. like user 1 is able to post only 10 posts in Cat 1, then he can also post another 10 in Cat 2 or wait till time is up

Answer (score 0):

bunu kullan

$author_posts = new WP_Query( array(
'cat' => '1,3',
'post_type'     => 'any',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'author'        => $user_id,
'fields'        => 'ids',
'monthnum'      => date( 'm' ), // Whatever the current month is
) );